# psycopg2.OperationalError: ERROR: pgbouncer cannot connect to server

Tags: python, postgresql

I am querying PostgreSQL using python and sometimes when I run the code, I get the following:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: ERROR:  pgbouncer cannot connect to server
```

I'm looking for advice on how I can handle the exception.

Code:

```
import psycopg2
while True:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="****", user="**, password="****", host="bdl****", port="5400")
        cur = conn.cursor()
        print ("Opened database successfully")    
        try:
            cur.execute('''select * from abc;''')
            conn.commit()
            conn.close()
        except psycopg2.OperationalError:
            continue
        break
```

Comment: Most likely, your pgsql server does not accept the connection. What is the `listen_ip` setting in your pgsql config?

Comment: Sorry, where do i find this

Comment: run `ps -aef | grep pgbouncer` - it will show you the config, then update your question with conn stings, eg `grep port /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini`

Comment: i tried this through command line  below are the details ""C:\>cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.5\bin>pg_config

SYSCONFDIR = C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/etc
PGXS = C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.5/lib/pgxs/src/makefiles/pgxs.mk
CONFIGURE = --enable-thread-safety --enable-integer-datetimes --enable-nls --wit
h-ldap --with-openssl --with-ossp-uuid --with-libxml --with-libxslt --with-tcl -
-with-perl --with-python
VERSION = PostgreSQL 9.5beta1""